# Polite way to suggest talking about something

Tags: word-choice, grammar, politeness

Is there a polite way to tell somebody that you want to tell him something, but only if he allows you to? For example, I'm talking to my friend and I want to tell him something about cats, but I'm not sure if he wants to listen to me. Is it possible to use something like this: 
- If you don't mind, I will  tell you about... 
or maybe 
- I could've told you about cats, if you wanted to... 
I understand that my explanation's a bit wierd, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Would you mind if I talked about [subject] for a minute?"

Comment: Thanks. 
Also, is it possible to use the following phrase?
-It reminds of a flying cat. _I could tell you if you would like to listen._

Comment: A more colloquial way might be "That reminds me of a flying cat - want to hear about it?" More formally "would you like to hear about it?" "It" is the choice if you're talking about a particular flying cat - "Would you like to hear about that?" is better if it's a topic instead of an example.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you would **request** a conversation about cats.

> politely or formally ask for.

Who wouldn't want to talk about cats for hours?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to [hortative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hortatorily?s=t) your friend that his cat is giving you the evil eye, stealing his beer, and that he should dump her?  Cat is a girl, right?

Comment: *horative* is a noun, adjective or adverb. It is *not* a verb. You can't *horative* someone.

Comment: hortatorily but I meant to add the term amblysia http://www.blackwellreference.com/public/tocnode?id=g9781444333275_chunk_g97814443332752_ss1-99 but you correct faster than I type, and refill my glass of wine....

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> "May I have a quick word about the supremacy of cats?"

or

> "Can I take this opportunity to talk about cats?"